# use variable String or char for Object name

Tags: java

```
int i = 0;
String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"; 
char letter = alphabet.charAt(i);

Letter a = new Letter(i,letter); Letter b = new Letter(i,letter); Letter c = new Letter(i,letter); Letter d = new Letter(i,letter); //...
```

is there a shorter way for the name to cycle through the alphabet?

Comment: What language is this?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming Java 8 (when the streams have been introduced), it becomes quite easy if we can simplify the `Letter` constructor a bit and take a tiny assumption - the `i` variable in your code is simply the index of the letter - in this case, you can calculate it without passing it to the constructor (`c - 'a'`), therefore I'll omit it in my constructor - it adds a lot of unnecessasry noise.

To make my answer more complete, let's assume that this is the `Letter` class we'll be using:

```
    public class Letter {
        char c; int index;

        public Letter(int c) {
            this.c = (char) c;
            this.index = c - 'a';
        }
    }
```

The entire thing can be accomplished within an oneliner:

```
List<Letter> l = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".chars().mapToObj(Letter::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The commented code looks like:

```
"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"        // Take the alphabet string
    .chars()                        // Turn the string into IntStream
    .mapToObj(Letter::new)          // Map all the characters into Letter constructor,
                                    // effectively transposing into stream of Letters
    .collect(Collectors.toList());  // Finally, collect all the Letters from the stream
                                    // into a list.
```

alternatively, if you'd like to get an array instead, you can use `.toArray();` instead of `.collect(...);`